# is it possible to handle compound layout (getLayout) with next-translate?

Tags: next.js

I try feed layout to my component by passing it like compound component after wrapper the component with another HOC, I use next-translate in my project.

```
// pages/test.tsx

function TestPage() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <>
      My testing page with translation
    </>
  );
}

TestPage.pageLayout = MyLayout;

export default withOtherHoc(TestPage);
```

and in the receive it from _app.tsx

```
// _app.tsx

function App({ Component, ...rest }) {

  const Layout = Component.pageLayout

  return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...props.pageProps} />
      </Layout>
  )
}
```

After a while I found out that next-translate Wrap the TestPage component with another Wrapper and it cause the compounding layout not detected.

I try add getStaticProps / getServerSideProps to bypass the wrapper component by next-translate and it's work but this is not what I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spend a while for debugging and find solution, I found this solution from github issue and it suit for this case. luckily for next-translate they provide the staticHoc config to passing hoist-non-react-statics. It used to copy the statics from the component and passing it to the next-translate wrapper so now the compound layout start to work again. Thank you to carlosriveroib and aralroca for the answer and question posting.

https://github.com/aralroca/next-translate/issues/717#issuecomment-957315046